# Processo não inicia no Player do Oracle BPM Composer 12c

Tags: oracle

Criei um processo utilizando o Oracle BPM Composer 12c, não estou conseguindo iniciar o Player para testar o processo antes de fazer a publicação no dominio.

Quando clico no botão do Player gera o seguinte erro no log do servidor:

> There was an error deploying the composite on DefaultServer: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("oracle.fabric.permission.CompositePermission" "default" "provision"): access denied ("oracle.fabric.permission.CompositePermission" "default" "provision").

Comment: Primeiramente seja bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português, veja o Tour para aproveitar melhor os recursos que o SO oferece: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. Consegue adicionar mais detalhes sobre o seu problema?